# Cannot mount usb stick after putting a Yosemite bootable image on it

Tags: linux, debian, mount, osx, fat

I was trying to put a bootable image on a USB stick so I could reinstall Mac OS Yosemite on my Macbook Pro (I am doing this all in in Linux so that's why this question is here). Once I finally converted the `.dmg` file into an `.iso` file, I ran the following command:

`sudo dd if=yosemite.iso of=/media/usb bs=4k; sync`

The command said it ran smoothly, but before I even ran it, I could mount the stick very easily; hell, even debian mounted it for me automatically. But afterwards, I could no longer do it. I now receive this error message when I try to mount it again:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/usb
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

And here's the output of `dmesg | tail`:

```
[ 5389.594434] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[ 5390.590509] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer Glide     1.27 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 5390.590764] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 5390.591569] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 31266816 512-byte logical blocks: (16.0 GB/14.9 GiB)
[ 5390.592944] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 5390.592946] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[ 5390.593171] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 5390.600178]  sdc: sdc1
[ 5390.601385] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 5494.716452] FAT-fs (sdc1): utf8 is not a recommended IO charset for FAT filesystems, filesystem will be case sensitive!
```

Is there any way to fix this? Will Debian even attempt to mount a Mac image?